# How to disable template insertion for `val`, `let`, etc. in `sml-mode`?

Tags: template

With the latest `sml-mode`(as of ELPA Jan 2022, Emacs 27), Emacs always creates some kind of pattern after a keyword such as `val`, `fun` and `let` and whitespace. So, if I type `fun` , I get

```
 fun  =  ^
```

where `^` indicates the cursor position.

I appreciate the hint about that pattern that I need to enter something before and after an equal sign `=`. But every time, I have to move the cursor back to where I was (i.e. after the `fun` and space), and then enter the function signature. Then, I need to move the cursor behind the `=` to enter the function body.

*How can I disable this template insertion to avoid the jumping around the `=`?*

Comment: How did you get the 2022 version? I can only see the 6.10 version from 2020.

Comment: Does setting `sml-abbrev-skeletons` to `nil` help?

Comment: @NickD Thanks! That does disable the template insertion. One additional question: this seems to disable all skeletons. If needed, can the same insertion behavior be manually/explicitly activated using a key combination for templates of other keywords such as `structure`?

Comment: I don't know. I just caught the variable out of the corner of my eye and suggested it to you. I didn't install or try out anything and I don't use the mode, so that's the extent of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @NickD, setting:

```
(setq sml-abbrev-skeletons nil)
```

in `init.el` disables any template insertion.